# How do I install windows vista home premium onto ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

How do I boot windows home premium onto ubuntu  using ubuntu?

Comment: Could rephrase this?  It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a virtual installation of this and other operating systems by installing [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/). Here is the [online user manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html).

You shouldn't have too much trouble using it once it is installed. If you have problems or specific questions related to doing this, please start a new thread with a clear title.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not clear from you question, if you want to run Windows Vista in virtual environment then links provided by @RyanLoremlpsum should help.

But if you want to do dual boot Windows Vista and Ubuntu... then this [Ubuntu manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) should help you. Or if you [Google](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=dual%20boot%20windows%20vista%20with%20ubuntu) you should find many many posts about this.